# What is "high taxed" defined as by the IRS?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-income

On form 1116 Foreign Tax Credit form there are references to HTKO yet the acronym is never defined. Googling leads me to believe that it stands for "High Tax Kick-Out". But I haven't been able to find a solid definition of what it really means. The [official page at the IRS site with directions for filling out this form](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1116) just references passive income that is "high taxed" for example:

> If you have passive income that is treated as general category income
>   because it is high taxed, use a separate column in Part I. Enter
>   "HTKO" on line g of Forms 1116 for passive category income and general
>   category income.

Comment: A quick search found [High Tax Kick Out (HTKO) – IRS Reduction in the Foreign Tax Credit](https://www.goldinglawyers.com/high-tax-kick-out-htko-irs-reduction-in-the-foreign-tax-credit/) which _seems_ to cover things, and could be the basis for an answer.